# Postgis – Opposite of ST_Within

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I'm trying to get all points that are NOT inside a few polygons:

```
SELECT pt.geom 
FROM points pt, polygons po
WHERE ST_Within(pt.geom, po.geom) = false;
```

But doesn't work – I get all the points instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why you see "all the points" is that you have more than one point and more than one polygon. If you had only one of either, it would work.

There are actually several ways to solve this one, but this is probably the most simple and quickest.

If you have a primary or unique key (e.g. `gid`):

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM points pt
WHERE pt.gid NOT IN (
    SELECT pt.gid FROM points pt, polygons po
    WHERE ST_Within(pt.geom, po.geom)
);
```

note that it will also return any points with NULL geometries.

Another method is to use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM points pt
EXCEPT SELECT pt.*
FROM points  pt, polygons po
WHERE ST_Within(pt.geom, po.geom);
```

And yet another method is to use ST_Union to fuse all the polygons into one large geometry, but this method would be much much slower.

Comment: This works for me. I came here because I was getting less results than expected with simple negation of ST_Within: SELECT pt.gid FROM points pt, polygons po
    WHERE NOT ST_Within(pt.geom, po.geom). Any idea why it can't be used like that?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT pt.geom 
FROM points pt, polygons po
WHERE ST_Within(pt.geom, po.geom)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.